# Bypassing input capacitor with a microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, operational-amplifier, basic

I am designing an amplifier stage and I would like to be able to switch between AC or DC input coupling. How do I achieve this with a microcontroller?

[image: schematic]

I was thinking about using a relay, but it seems like an overkill for such an easy task.

Comment: A relay is a *very* easy, *very* reliable way of doing this. You'd better have a *very* good reason for dismissing it...

Comment: Well, relays are quite chunky and relatively expensive. I will have 4 input channels on a PCB which is why I wanted to avoid using relays

Comment: Telecom relays are fairly cheap.  Is the space that small?

Comment: @v.m.: what qualifies as chunky for you? they make them in under \$1 cm^2\$

Comment: I could go for relays, of course, but I liked the idea of analog switches since I can achieve what I need with one small package and no external circuitry. Could you suggest an inexpensive latching relay that operates at 3VDC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can solve this problem using an analogue switch part. Use the switch to short across the capacitor when the switch is actively closed.

There are many analogue switch parts available in the market place. Selection will depend upon a number of factors:

1. Number of switches you need in one package
2. Frequency response you can expect through the switch when it is ON
3. Analogue voltage range allowed through the switch with a given voltage/gnd rail supplied to the part.
4. Series ON resistance of the switch on ohms.

If you are not looking for the highest in performance the application that you showed may very well be met using a 74HC4066 or similar type part.

Comment: I wasn't aware of analogue switches. Learned something new today, thanks!